# How to remove the empty elements from the json using object mapper java

Tags: java, objectmapper

So I have a object mapper (jackson version is 2.9.5) with following values:

```java
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
objectMapper.setSerializationInclusion(JsonInclude.Include.NON_EMPTY);
```

but when the final json is created I still see the empty elements like below:

```json
{"address":[],"customerKycDetails":[],"security":[]}
```

So can I know how exactly to configure the objectMapper to remove all the empty object like this: `"security":[]`?

I was thinking JsonInclude.Include.NON_EMPTY should work but it is not working.

Comment: Why are you thinking that your ObjectMapper will be used? If we use the Spring framework you need to declare ObjectMapper  as bean

Comment: because for the resttemplate I am passing the json string (coverted by objectmapper that I have above)instead of the actual request object in which case as you said Spring will do the marshal/unmarshalling.

Comment: Could you please describe the class which needs to be serialized?